# Firemonkey XE4 iOS loading a PNG with transparency

Tags: ios, delphi, png, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have a PNG of a watermark that makes use of transparency that I load at run time from a .res file. It comes through as entirely black (due to mishandling the transparency).

```
RS := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'WATERMARK', RT_RCDATA);
Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(768, 960);
Bitmap.LoadFromStream(RS);
Image1.Bitmap := Bitmap;
Image1.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.iwStretch;
```

I am using the same code with a bitmap that I have dramatically reduced in size in the mean time, but I would rather be using the PNG with the transparency and resolution. Is there anyway to make the TBitmap in Firemonkey correctly handle the transparency of the PNG?

Everything I have read on this topic involves using VCL classes or properties that are unavailable in firemonkey

Comment: Are you having the same issue on the Windows platform or just the iOS?

Comment: I have a PNG with transparency and when loading it in a TImage control on a FireMonkey mobile form, the transparency is ignored and replaced with white.  XE5 iOS app.